# Get earliest date items after certain date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I use this query to get the earliest date records:

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM shop_meta tt
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT seller_name, MIN(check_date) AS MinDateTime
         FROM shop_meta
         GROUP BY seller_name) groupedtt
    ON  tt.seller_name = groupedtt.seller_name
    AND tt.check_date = groupedtt.MinDateTime
order by seller_name
```

I am trying to get all the earliest date records after certain date only.

I tried adding:

`having MIN(check_date) > $date`

`having groupedtt.MinDateTime > $date`

`having tt.check_date > $date`

`having check_date > $date`

and

`where MIN(check_date) > $date`

`where groupedtt.MinDateTime > $date`

`where tt.check_date > $date`

`where check_date > $date`

before `order by` in a query, but I guess I am doing it wrong. Please help!

Edit:

Sample table:

```
seller_name status  check_date
Seller 1    open    2016-05-09
Seller 1    open    2016-05-25
Seller 1    open    2016-05-26
Seller 2    open    2016-05-10
Seller 2    open    2016-05-20
Seller 3    open    2016-05-09
```

with the `$date = 2016-05-19` expected results:

```
seller_name status  check_date
Seller 1    open    2016-05-25
Seller 2    open    2016-05-20
```

Comment: Add the where clause to the sub-query instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems quite simple:

```
....
(SELECT seller_name, MIN(check_date) AS MinDateTime
 FROM   shop_meta
 WHERE  check_date > $date
 GROUP BY seller_name) groupedtt
....
```

Comment: After applying still returns all the earliest dates including the ones before the `$date`...

Comment: @Acidon, seems odd. This query looks just fine. Can you add some sample table data to your question, and also the expected result!

Comment: There is a minor typo here. There is an extra closing bracket after $date. Remove that and replacing the sub query in the original query with this sub query should give you what you want.

Comment: @Kickstart I spotted the extra bracket right away, the output is still wrong :(

Comment: @jarlh I've updated the question with sample table data and expected result

Comment: @Acidon, Which is exactly what you get with the above answer... Time to upvote and accept this answer!

Comment: @jarlh If it would work for me, do you think I wouldn't accept the answer without going through editing the question with extra data? For some reason it returns me all the earliest dates including the ones before `$date`...

Comment: @Acidon It should work (assuming you are passing in a date in ccyy-mm-dd format), and the sqlfiddle above shows that it does work normally. The exception I can see is if you do not surround $date with quotes.

Comment: @Kickstart you are correct, once the quotes has been added, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT tt.*
    FROM shop_meta tt
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT seller_name, MIN(check_date) AS MinDateTime
        FROM shop_meta
        GROUP BY seller_name
HAVING MIN(Check_date)>$date) groupedtt
    ON tt.seller_name = groupedtt.seller_name
    AND tt.check_date = groupedtt.MinDateTime order by seller_name
```

Comment: After applying still returns all the earliest dates including the ones before the `$date`